# performance issue with sql time interval evaluation

Tags: sql, oracle

There exists a table to log information by timestamp:

```
-- table with timestamp, request_id (in production further columns)
create table log_data(dttm date, request_id number);

-- test data: timestamps in range [sysdate-3; sysdate], request_id in [1, 3]
insert into log_data
  (select sysdate - dbms_random.value(0, 3) as dttm, 1 as request_id
     from dual
   connect by level <= 10000
   union all
   select sysdate - dbms_random.value(0, 3) as dttm, 2 as request_id
     from dual
   connect by level <= 10000
   union all
   select sysdate - dbms_random.value(0, 3) as dttm, 3 as request_id
     from dual
   connect by level <= 10000);

create index log_data_idx on log_data(dttm, request_id);
```

What is the best way to count requests by request_id within a time interval (let's say of an hour)?

First (bad) try:

```
explain plan for
-- count same requests in time interval of an hour
  with log_data_per_hour as
   (select d.request_id,
           d.dttm as dttm_from,
           d.dttm + 1 / 24 as dttm_to,
           count(*) as total
      from log_data dd, log_data d
     where dd.dttm between d.dttm and d.dttm + 1 / 24
       and dd.request_id = d.request_id
     group by d.request_id, d.dttm, d.dttm + 1 / 24)

  -- find maximum per request    
  select request_id,
         max(dttm_from) keep(dense_rank first order by total) dttm,
         max(total)
    from log_data_per_hour
   group by request_id;

select plan_table_output
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', null, null));

/*
    Plan hash value: 2118911212

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |          |     3 |   105 |  1410  (98)| 00:00:24 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY NOSORT |          |     3 |   105 |  1410  (98)| 00:00:24 |
|   2 |   VIEW                |          |   832K|    27M|  1410  (98)| 00:00:24 |
|   3 |    SORT GROUP BY      |          |   832K|    34M|  1410  (98)| 00:00:24 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN         |          |   832K|    34M|  1379  (98)| 00:00:24 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOG_DATA | 31612 |   679K|    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOG_DATA | 31612 |   679K|    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("DD"."REQUEST_ID"="D"."REQUEST_ID")
       filter("DD"."DTTM">="D"."DTTM" AND 
              "DD"."DTTM"<=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."DTTM")+.041666666666666666666666666666
              6666666667)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=4)
*/
```

Second try:

```
explain plan for
-- count same requests in time interval of an hour
  with log_data_per_hour as
   (select d.request_id,
           d.dttm as dttm_from,
           d.dttm + 1 / 24 as dttm_to,
           (select count(*)
              from log_data dd
             where dd.dttm between d.dttm and d.dttm + 1 / 24
               and dd.request_id = d.request_id) as total
      from log_data d)

  -- find maximum per request    
  select request_id,
         max(dttm_from) keep(dense_rank first order by total) dttm,
         max(total)
    from log_data_per_hour
   group by request_id;

select plan_table_output
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', null, null));

/*
Plan hash value: 1803512279

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |              | 31612 |   679K|    20  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |              |     1 |    22 |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER           |              |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| LOG_DATA_IDX |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |  SORT GROUP BY     |              | 31612 |   679K|    20  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOG_DATA     | 31612 |   679K|    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(:B1<=:B2+.0416666666666666666666666666666666666667)
   3 - access("DD"."DTTM">=:B1 AND "DD"."REQUEST_ID"=:B2 AND 
              "DD"."DTTM"<=:B3+.0416666666666666666666666666666666666667)
       filter("DD"."REQUEST_ID"=:B1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=4)

    */
```

I guess there is a much better solution than subselecting because this is still quite expensive.

Any improvements are much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess `select to_char(dttm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'), count(*) from log_data group by to_char(dttm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24')` is not what you want? It is a slightly different thing as it counts rows that occur at the same "numerical hour" (e.g. between 00:00 and 01:00, or between 18:00 and 19:00), not rows that are at least an hour apart

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right, this is not what i want :-) I don't want the maximum values by hour but by time interval of an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of rows in an interval can be done efficiently using a window function using a range:

```
select request_id, 
       dttm as dttm_from,
       count(*) over (partition by request_id order by dttm range between current row and interval '1' hour following) as total
from log_data
```

The above will count the number of rows per requeset_id starting with the "current" row and all rows that lie within a 1 hour interval after that. The advantage is that this requires only a single table scan

This can be used to replace the CTE:

```
with log_data_per_hour as (
  select request_id, 
         dttm as dttm_from,
         count(*) over (partition by request_id order by dttm range between current row and interval '1' hour following) as total
  from log_data
)
select request_id,
       max(dttm_from) keep(dense_rank first order by total) dttm,
       max(total)
from log_data_per_hour
group by request_id;
```

This returns the following execution plan on my computer:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3005213820                                                      

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          | 29920 |  1022K|    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY NOSORT|          | 29920 |  1022K|    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW               |          | 29920 |  1022K|    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    WINDOW SORT       |          | 29920 |   642K|    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOG_DATA | 29920 |   642K|    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note                                                                             
-----                                                                            
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

On my computer this runs in about 50ms whereas your second statement takes about 600ms (average of 5 runs).

If I swap the columns in the index, I get a better runtime for the your second statement as well (about 200ms) which makes sense because it's more efficient to use the first column of the index to find matching rows in the scalar sub-select.